# Lisp: IF condition using AND operator

Tags: syntax, lisp, common-lisp

I making this function.

```
(f 3 4) (sum = 7) 
(f 'a 'b) (not num!)
```

My problem is how can I make if condition using and operator.

I try....

1. `(IF (and (typep a 'integer) (typep b 'integer)) (1) (0))`
2. `(IF (and ((typep a 'integer)) ((typep b 'integer))) (1) (0))`
3. `(IF ((and ((typep a 'integer)) ((typep b 'integer)))) (1) (0))`

But it doesn't work.
`(1)` and `(0)` is used temporarily.

Could I get some lisp syntax help?

Comment: The first one should work when you remove the parentheses around the numbers (change `(1) (0)` to `1 0`). You could also use `integerp` instead of `(typep ... 'integer)`

Comment: next time please copy and paste your code AND the error message you got. we will teach you how to understand the error messages.

Comment: I will. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important thing you need to learn about Lisp at this moment is that *parens matter*.

In C you can write `1+3`, `(1)+3`, `(((1+3)))` and they all mean the same thing. In lisp they are very very different:

- `a` means "the value of the *variable* named `a`".
- `(a)` means "the return value of the *function* named `a` called without any arguments".
- `((a))` is a syntax error (but see PPS)

So, every version with `((...))` is outright wrong.

Since there is no function named `1`, the first version is no good either.

What you need is:

```
(if (and (typep a 'integer)
         (typep b 'integer))
    1
    0)
```

Note formatting and indentation.
Lispers read code by indentation, *not* parens, so proper indentation is critical.
Note that Emacs (and maybe some other Lisp-specific IDEs) will indent lisp code for you.

**PS.** The description of what you are trying to accomplish is unclear, but it might be that the easiest way is to use generic functions:

```
(defgeneric f (a b)
  (:method ((a integer) (b integer))
    (+ a b)))
(f 1 2)
==> 3
(f 1 'a)    
*** - NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD: When calling #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION F> with
      arguments (1 A), no method is applicable.
```

**PPS.** Eventually you will see legitimate `((...) ...)`, e.g., [`cond`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm):

```
(defun foo (a)
  (cond ((= a 1) "one")
        ((= a 2) "two")
        (t "many")))
(foo 1)
==> "one"
(foo 3)
==> "many"
```

or [lambda forms](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababd.htm):

```
((lambda (x) (+ x 4)) 5)
==> 9
```

but you do not need to worry about those yet.